# Mapping a C# shell extension drive to a network drive

Tags: c#, windows, shell-extensions

I am currently working on a shell extension in C# using the library EZShellExtensions. The application basically displays the data present in database like a windows folder with custom folder and file icons. It also gives the opportunity for copying into and from the application . Copying into application is done by calling a web service to add and get files from database. My application is currently being displayed as a Drive in MyComputer. I want to map this application to a network drive( or assign a drive letter ) so that I can access the files in app from command prompt or any other application like X:\example_folder\example_file. Can you help on how to modify the application for this ?

Comment: WinApi functions cannot access to ShellApi folders.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov : Thank you . Is it not possible to create a shortcut to a COM object using its CLSID? . Can you suggest some other alternative. Ultimately I want to access folders in the drive through a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and was able to map my app (similar to google drive ) as a network drive.
1. Right click on my computer and select Map a network drive.
2. On the window that comes select the option " Connect to a website that you can use to store your documents and pictures " ( will be shown as a link )
3. On the next window that comes, proceed to next window by clicking next.
4. On the next window select " Choose a custom network location" and click next.
5. This window ask for you internet or network address. Here you have to give the CLSID(Windows class identifier) of your app. Or CLSID of mycomputer/clsid of your app.

you can find more details about CLSID [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424(v=vs.85).aspx)! .